# Python: escape quotes with slashes

Tags: python

I'm trying to escape quote marks in Python, but my intended plan does not work:

```
>>> s = 'Hi "there"'

>>> s.replace('"', '\"')
'Hi "there"'

>>> s.replace('"', '\\"')
'Hi \\"there\\"'
```

What is the proper way to single-escape quotes within a string (e.g. make `'Hi \"there\"'`)?

Comment: You don't need to escape them.

Comment: Yes I do, I'm posting data via TCP sockets and need to escape all sorts of quotes...

Comment: You don't need to escape double quotes to send them over a TCP socket.

Comment: TCP socket should accept bytes. `'This is my "quoted" string'` is properly escaped already

Comment: @wim I have arbitrary strings passing through a pipe that contain all manners of symbols like ` that break posted data. I'd like to escape them all. Question deals with one of these special characters, but I'm looking for a general escape solution...

Comment: Escaping them does not change the value, it only makes the syntax correct in special cases

Comment: Then you need a serialiser and/or an encoding, not escaping.

Comment: If your question is *about sockets*, then post a [mcve] about what you are actually doing. See [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Your second example works perfectly, it's only the output from Python that's confusing you. Letting Python display the raw value doubles up the \\, use `print` to see what's really there.

Comment: @wim You don't know what the poster is trying to achieve. Yes, you can post any data to a socket. This may be a part of a text protocol, or a part of serialising some data. We don't have enough information to say one way or another. Telling the author they don't need it is not a great approach. You can ask for more details if you think that's the case.

Comment: Yeah, well, they didn't post what they are really trying to achieve (classic XY problem).  But I know enough about socket communication to say that replacing " with \" is really barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: @wim cricket_007 ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000 viraptor MarkRansom thanks for your comments. I'll delete this and make a new question. Thought I could solve this without getting down to implementation details--looks like I may be wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct. The string that's displayed is the result of `repr(your_result)` which includes its own escaping. You can get the actual value by printing it.

```
>>> result = s.replace('"', '\\"')

>>> result
'Hi \\"there\\"'

>>> print(result)
Hi \"there\"

>>> print(repr(result))
'Hi \\"there\\"'
```

Comment: I can't delete this question, but didn't know about repr, which helps, so I'll accept this. Never thought a string replacement question would trigger such wild responses!

Comment: The first one is correct. Since the second one has backslashes when it prints, it means it didn't escape the `"`. The first one prints it without backslashes, which means it is escaped.